# Can PCA be formulated as a convex problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, principal-component-analysis

The PCA objective function can be formulated in several equivalent ways. Are any of them convex?

Let $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$ denote a matrix of mean-centered data. One way of viewing PCA (with $K$ components) is in terms of reconstruction error:

$$
\underset{\mathbf{U}, \mathbf{V}}{\text{minimize}} \quad \lVert \mathbf{X} - \mathbf{UV}^T \lVert_F^2
$$

with $\mathbf{U} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times K}$ and $\mathbf{V} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}$. This objective is clearly nonconvex due to the $\mathbf{UV}^T$ term.

PCA can be equivalently viewed as identifying directions, $\mathbf{w}_i$ below, of maximal variance in the data:
$$
\underset{\mathbf{w}_i}{\text{maximize}} \quad \sum_{i=1}^K \mathbf{w}_i^T \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{w}_i \\
$$
$$
\text{subject to} \quad \mathbf{w}_i^T \mathbf{w}_j = \delta_{ij} \\
$$

Where $\delta_{ij} = 1$ if $i = j$ and $\delta_{ij} = 0$ if $i \neq j$ (i.e. the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)). Here the objective function is convex, but the orthogonality constraint is nonconvex. Furthermore, you are maximizing a convex function, so the overall problem is nonconvex.

(Note that I don't necessarily care whether $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ are orthogonal matrices in the first optimization problem, but the orthogonality constraint is necessary in the second problem to prevent all $\mathbf{w}_i$ from converging to the top eigenvector.)

**Question:** Are there any manipulations to the above equations that would formulate PCA as a convex optimization problem?

PCA can be solved efficiently via the singular value decomposition (SVD) of $\mathbf{X}$ or eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix. Furthermore, while the first formulation I gave above is nonconvex, it can be shown that all local minima correspond to a global solution, and all non-optimal critical points are saddle points (e.g. [Baldi & Hornik, 1989](https://doi.org/10.1016/0893-6080(89)90014-2)).

Does this special structure / simplicity suggest that there is a really a convex formulation?

Comment: No, PCA is not convex, and cannot be made so.

Comment: If I write $J(w) = \frac{w^T X^T X w}{w^T w}$ then $\partial J = 0 \Leftrightarrow w$ is an eigenvector of $X^T X$ which has more than one solution, so it is not a convex problem.

Comment: There is no known way to formulate it as a convex problem. However, I wouldn't make claims like "cannot be formulated", since there are many nonconvex problems that were formulated as convex ones by a change of variables. e.g. Geometric Programming.

Comment: @Alex I have a reasonable amount of experience in this area (including with geometric programming). I remain comfortable with my claim until proven wrong.

Comment: I know. You are one of the developers of CVX :)
However, I am never comfortable with such claims.

Comment: @Alex I do hear where you're coming from. My claim is something a gambler would be happy to put money on, but that doesn't make it technically correct. But I say it not just as a gambler, but as someone who tries to educate and influence. Convexity is a rare and fragile property; it is the exception rather than the rule. And I encounter far, far too many wishful thinkers who would love to find a transformation to turn their pet model convex. I've yet to see one---and yet I _have_ seen nonconvex problems that people didn't _realize_ could be convexified.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, What do you think about the link in the answer: https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt-S15/scribes/26-nonconvex-scribed.pdf ?

Answer (score 1):

@Michael, as @Alex implied, "cannot be formulated" is not well defined.
For example of convex formulation with zero gap, see:
[https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-S15/scribes/26-nonconvex-scribed.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt-S15/scribes/26-nonconvex-scribed.pdf)